A capacitor partially filled with dielectric
Assume a parallel plate capacitor that was charged up to $Q_0$ from a source $U_0$ and then disconnected from the voltage source. The plates have an area $A$ and the distance between the plates is $d$. Now, I stick a dielectric to one of the plates such that it covers half of the area of the plate and half the distance between the plates. Mentally split the capacitor into the grid shown in the following image.

I want to calculate the electric displacement field in the zones $II_{a}$ and $II_{b}$ of the capacitor after the dielectric was placed:
$$D'_{{II}_a} = \frac{Q'_{{II}_a}}{A/2} = \frac{C'_{{II}_a} U'_{{II}_a}}{A/2}$$
I know that the charge on the plates before and after placing the dielectric is the same, implying the following:
$$CU_0 = C'U'$$
$$\Leftrightarrow U' = \frac{C}{C'}U_0$$
Now, I want to understand why $U_{{II}_a}$ should equal $U'$ (i.e. $U_{{II}_a} = U'$)? Does the potential difference reduce by the same amount in all the zones of the capacitor?

For some background, let's remind ourselves that the electric field is a conservative field. Because of this, we can define potentials that are independent of the particular path of integration. So you could define some other potential $U_{a,b,c}$ where the path of integration criss-crosses across all the different zones. As long as it starts on the first plate, and ends on the second, this will be the same potential as all the other potentials.
The second part of the explanation is that we're assuming the plates are conductive. This means there can be no electric field inside the plates, and the potential across the area of the plate is consistent.
Combine these, and the potential from any point on the first plate, to any point on the second plate will always be identical.
If for whatever reason, the charges got "stuck", and couldn't move around (so the plate is no longer a perfect conductor), then inserting or removing the dielectric would cause the potentials to change across the different zones.
